# How to use the intersection of 2 dataframe as index and then divide one by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have 2 dataframes. I attempt to calculate the division of intersected rows of these 2 dataframes. That is to firstly find all of codes that belong to both of two dataframes, and then let each of element in df1 be divided by the corresponding element in df2. Please note that codes of df1 and df2 are not necessarily in same length or sequence. (code is index but not one of the columns in the dataframes)

df1:

```
code    20180101   20180102    ...    20181231
001         3         5        ...       5
002         2         1        ...       10
003         1         1        ...       5
...          
1230        1         2        ...       0.5
1231        2         2        ...       5
```

df2:

```
code    20180101   20180102    ...    20181231
001         6         10        ...      10
002         4         3        ...       2
004         1         1        ...       5
...          
1230        4         3        ...       1
1231        2         2        ...       5
```

I tried to merge these two dataframes first but I don't know what to do next. Or if there is any more efficient way? My ideal result is:

```
code     20180101    20180102   ...   20181231
001         0.5         0.5     ...      0.5     
002         0.5         0.3333  ...       5
...
1230        0.25        0.6667  ...       2
1231        1           1       ...       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For df1, df2 have the same index `code` but not necessarily in same length or sequence, try:

```
df3 = (df1 / df2).dropna()
```

### Test Run:

```
print(df1)
Output:
    
      20180101  20180102  20181231
code                              
1            3         5         5
2            2         1        10
3            1         1         5
4           10        20        30
    
print(df2)
Output:
    
      20180101  20180102  20181231
code                              
1            6        10        10
2            4         3         2
3            1         1         5
5           20        30        40
    
df3 = (df1 / df2).dropna()
    
print(df3)
Output:
    
      20180101  20180102  20181231
code                              
1          0.5  0.500000       0.5
2          0.5  0.333333       5.0
3          1.0  1.000000       1.0
```

Comment: I am sorry but I could not assume df1 and df2 share the same length and sequence.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make myself clear in the beginning

Comment: @ZiyiGao  amended as per the clarification